# Javascript String Var + jQuery Textbox Val

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Anyone know why the following code doesn't seem to work? I'm trying to append whatever is in the textbox to the URL string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myurl.com/something.php?myname='+$('#myname').val(),
    success: function(point) {
        var series = chart.series[0],
        shift = series.data.length > 20;
        chart.series[0].addPoint(point[0], true, shift);
            chart.series[1].addPoint(point[1], true, shift);
            setTimeout(requestData, 5000);  
         },
         cache: false
     });
```

Comment: So the `**` indicate what doesn't work?  How do you know it doesn't work and why?

Comment: What's not working?  Any JS errors?  What is the typical content of `myname` textbox?

Comment: thx to that ninja up there for editing whew :)

Comment: @justkt: I thought the `**` were from formatting mistakes of the first revision, my mistake. Feel free to correct.

Comment: @Wesley - in the first revision it bolded the line, and given that the OP says "I'm trying to append whatever is in the textbox to the URL string," I'm pretty sure that line is whatever is failing, probably in the append.

Answer (score 3):

You did not let us know what is not working. `$('#myname').val()` should work if you really have a `myname` object.

However, I could not help noticing that you are requesting via POST, but at the same time you are building a query string. Try changing the type to `GET` and see how it goes.

Comment: Its perfectly OK to have variables in query string and post data and both can be accessed on the server side separately but this could be the mistake OP is making.

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong according to what OP gave us.

Answer (score 1):

May be the value of the element contains characters that can alter the meaning of query strings, e.g. if the value begins with `&asdf`, the url becomes `http://myurl.com/something.php?myname=&asdf`. If so, try this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://myurl.com/something.php?myname=' + encodeURIComponent($('#myname').val()), // pass via GET
     // I assume there is no data to pass -- uncomment otherwise
     // data: {
     //     name1: value1,
     //     name2: value2,
     // },
     success:
     .
     .
     .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a variable instead of doing it inline like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $("#myname").val();
    //any validation would occur here
    var posturl = "http://myurl.com/something.php?myname" + name;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: posturl,
      data: data,
      success: success
      dataType: dataType
    });

});
</script>
<body>
    <input id="myname" value="John Doe" />
</body>
```